# How do I perform clientside web-scraping with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, yql

How is this done without violating the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)? I have tried, unsuccessfully, to use a website like http://anyorigin.com/ but it does not work. How do I make this happen?

Comment: see my [post](http://scraping.pro/web-scraping-with-javascript-load-html-page/) on my experience with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT 4/1/20 - Fixing nonfunctional code:

Well, it turns out that YQL doesn't work anymore, but we won't let that stop us.

It turns out that there is a free service called [CloudQuery](https://github.com/t9tio/cloudquery) that we can use to accomplish the same thing quite easily. Unfortunately, there is a very low limit to the number of calls you can make over a period of time.

```js
var myUrl = "https://cloudquery.t9t.io/query?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F5732397%2Fstardustgogeta&selectors=*:nth-child(2)%20%3E%20*:nth-child(1)%20%3E%20*:nth-child(1)%20%3E%20*:nth-child(1)%20%3E%20*:nth-child(1)%20%3E%20*:nth-child(2)%20%3E%20*%20%3E%20*:nth-child(1)";

fetch(myUrl).then(r => r.json()).then(r => {document.write(r.contents[0].innerText)});
```

### Old answer:

It turns out that Yahoo's [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (Yahoo Query Language) can use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) to find elements of a page's HTML online.

Simply include the following in your document:

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<script>
    var yqlCallback = function(data){
     var rep = data.query.results.div;
        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = "StardustGogeta's reputation is "+rep+'.';
    };
</script>
<script type='application/javascript' src="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20content%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F5732397%2Fstardustgogeta'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22reputation%22%5D'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=yqlCallback"></script>
```